# Keynote: how to export all slides as one single page?

Tags: macos, export, macos-monterey, presentation, keynote

I have a Keynote presentation in which a slide smoothly flows into the next one, graphically speaking. Is there a way to export Keynote slides as one single long page, JPEG / PDF? (Any option would suffice actually.) Didn't find any solution in Export settings and no info on the web.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I guess not, the option would be using a specific service to merge exported PDF-file with multiple pages into a single-page PDF. The one I found: https://avepdf.com/convert-to-one-page-pdf